# Access MongoDB nested object using variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6, mongojs

Using the npm package mongojs, I need to access nested objects using a variable. The following, however, does not work:

```
    let userID = req.user._id,
        marketName = req.body.marketName,
        itemName = req.body.item.itemName,
        crossOff = req.body.item.isCrossed;

    markets.updateOne(
       {
        _id: userID,
        "marketList.marketName": marketName
      },
      {$set : {`marketList.$.shoppingList.${itemName}.isCrossed`: crossOff}},
      (err, doc) => {
        if(err) { res.status(400).send('Bad Request') }
        else { res.status(204) }
        res.end();
      });
   });
```

As you cannot use template strings in this situation, hence the `unexpected template string` error.

I am aware that it is possible to use bracket-notation to use a variable as a key, however, this will not help my situation since I am unable to set a variable with the entire key stored in it as a string.

To help, here is a sample the document structure:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(...),
  marketList: [
    { marketName: 'ralphs',
      shoppingList: {
        "cookies": {  itemName: "cookies", isCrossed: false },
        "moar cookies": { itemName: "moar cookies", isCrossed: true }
    },
    {
      marketName: 'gelsons',
      shoppingList: {
        "even moar cookies": { itemName: "even moar cookies", isCrossed: true }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What are my options?

Comment: Why are you unable to just create an object and use brackets for the key? Template strings are just syntactic sugar, if you can use those, you can use an object.

Comment: @adeneo I have no idea what the location of the marketName is ahead of time. Otherwise I would simply use bracket notation.

Comment: As in -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/j7tc7muL/1/

Comment: Well I'll be damned. Thank you @adeneo I did not know I could set a query in such a way.

Comment: You're welcome, I added it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the query in advance, that way bracket notation can be used for the key

```
let userID   = req.user._id,
  marketName = req.body.marketName,
  itemName   = req.body.item.itemName,
  crossOff   = req.body.item.isCrossed,
  query      = {};

query["marketList.$.shoppingList." + itemName + ".isCrossed"] = crossOff;

markets.updateOne({
        _id: userID,
        "marketList.marketName": marketName
    }, {
        $set: query
    }, (err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
        res.status(400).send('Bad Request');
        } else {
        res.status(204);
        }
        res.end();
    });
});
```